# What are the economic peer-reviewed journals devoted to literature review?

Tags: econometrics, reference-request, soft-question, research

I am looking for economic/econometrics journals committed to publish just (or mainly) literature review.

So far I've found:

- [Journal of Economic Literature](https://www.aeaweb.org/journals/jel)
- [Journal of Economic Surveys](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/14676419)

What are some others?

Answer (score 6):

Elsevier has a series of [Handbooks in Economics](https://www.sciencedirect.com/browse/journals-and-books/h?contentType=HB&searchPhrase=Economics) that contain field/topic-specific survey chapters.

Sometimes the [*New Palgrave Dictionary of Economics*](https://link.springer.com/referencework/10.1057/978-1-349-95121-5) has entries that are helpful for literature review purposes.

Answer (score 5):

The Annual Review of Economics is a nice one to look into

https://www.annualreviews.org/journal/economics

Answer (score 4):

I think the Journal of Economic Literature is your best bet. The Journal of Economic Perspectives might also have some things of interest.